# Parse - getting the object id with a value

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform

I need to get the object `id` of a `PFObject` but using a column. 
For example, I have a column `name` and I want to get the object `id` using `name`.

I have a PFObject. It has values like: name, photo objectId and more...
I have to get the object using one of the values and not object id

For example.. This method gives me the object using object id and I want to get the object using "name" for example.

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"GameScore"];

// Retrieve the object by id
[query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:@"xWMyZ4YEGZ" block:^(PFObject *gameScore, NSError *error) {

    // some code

}];
```

thanks!

Comment: could you please add some depth to your question? Or some code examples, that would be a major help on our side

Comment: Why? Is my question not clear?

Comment: Not at all, it's very broad

Comment: read the docs on parse.com regarding queries.  https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#queries/iOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Parse Docs](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#queries/iOS). Their docs are excellent.

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"GameScore"];
[query whereKey:@"name" equalTo:@"A Name Here"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
  // Your code here where you can extract the id using objects[i].objectID
}];
```

Comment: I am new to this web site... Did I accept your answer? I clicked the V icon

Comment: Welcome to the community! Yes, that's how you do it. Accept an answer if it works and upvote answers or comments that are useful.

Comment: It is important to note that strings are CASE-SENSITIVE, so if name is `A Name here` and you search for `A Name Here` you won't find a match ("h" vs "H"). There other topics on making search fields to solve this.